# Consuming camunda rest api in angular project but i get the error no cross origin how to fix it?

Tags: java, angular

I'm getting error of no cross origin while using camunda rest api

```
startProcess2(id:any) : Observable<any>{

   return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/rest/process-definition/key/tickma/start`, 
    {
      "variables": {
        "saf" : {
          "value" : "false",
          "type": "String"
        }
      },
      "businessKey" : "id"


    },

`httpOptions   );}  const httpOptions : any    = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    //'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',

  })
};
```

this is in service  in angular         `

Comment: Add your code related to this

Comment: add it to question.

Comment: i Have changed the question this is the methode in the angular service